# How do I correct npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons resulting in err

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

When trying to install fortauwsome getting err password is missing, however I have checked an reset my password on nmp ok

(venv) PS C:\Users\MikeOliver\KDConnectorGUI\KDConnectorGUI\src> npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an 
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MikeOliver\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-29T02_13_46_474Z-debug-0.log
```

log relative block

```
 verbose stack HttpErrorAuthUnknown: Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://npm.fontawesome.com/",service="npm.fontawesome.com"
47 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\lib\check-response.js:80:17
47 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
47 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:87:19)
47 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:118:23)
47 verbose stack     at async [nodeFromEdge] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1059:19)
47 verbose stack     at async [buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:929:11)
47 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:207:7)
47 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
47 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:159:5)
47 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:146:5)
48 verbose statusCode 401
```

[image: I was able to login to npm (see attached) site with current password.]
Obviously was expecting the install to work.  I have 2fa enabled and all working fine except for this insall.

Comment: Logging in on the website is not the same as logging in with the command-line tool. See `npm help login`. With fontawesome specifically, from what I understand if you're using the registry mentioned in the error, you must be a paid subscriber to their packages, and even if you are, their auth seems to frequently break. There's a long discussion [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17147) with no real resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The error you received indicates an authentication issue with the npm registry. It seems that your saved npm credentials are either incorrect or out of date. You need to try these:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm logout
npm login
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```